# How to launch the Bootstrap Tour on button click?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-tour

I am wanting to find out why my Bootstrap Tour isn't launching on click.

See image below for reference and code also. Note, I left out the majority of the page's code because I didn't want to overwhelm you. Hopefully, there is enough here for you to get this tour working.

What I am doing wrong?

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tour/0.11.0/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Button for Tour Start -->
<a id="MSL-initialize-tour" class="MSL-tour-button MSL-white-button" href="#">START TOUR</a>


<img id="MSL-tour-welcome" class="MSL-Headine-Desktop" src="https://sephora.csod.com/clientimg/sephora/welcome/1-22-18_Headline_V2.png" />


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tour/0.11.0/js/bootstrap-tour.min.js"></script>


<script>

// Instance the tour
var tour = new Tour({
  steps: [ 
  {
    element: "#MSL-tour-welcome",
    placement: "top",
    title: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span> Welcome to MSL!",
    content: "Press 'next' to see page features"
  }
]});


$('#MSL-initialize-tour').click(function(){
  tour.init();
  tour.start();
});

</script>
```

Comment: This seems like a debugging problem. What have you do so far to debug this? Is your click event working? Have you added `console.log` commands to see how far it gets?

Answer (score 3):

- The first problem I see is that your integrity does not match your
  file for the `bootstrap-tour.min.css` on line 2.

  ```
  integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
  ```

  That value is for `bootstrap-theme.min.css`. You can see that it has an error with the integrity check in your console when you run it. Either remove the integrity check or find the correct integrity value.
- The second problem is that you are using the slim version of jQuery.
  You can see this error as you get `TypeError stop is not a function`
  in the console log. You should use jquery-x.x.x.min.js instead.
- The third problem is that you are attempting to initialize the tour
  every time you press the button, when you only need to initialize it
  once. Therefore you should only call tour.start() one time, and
  then call tour.restart() after that.

The code below starts the tour immediately on page startup, but just so you get the idea the clicks afterwards work.

```
  tour.init();
  tour.start();
  $('#MSL-initialize-tour').click(function(){
     tour.restart();
  });
```

**tl;dr** The integrity value of the tour css is incorrect, shouldn't use the slim version of jquery, and need to restart the tour instead of re-initializing after every click.

Comment: Wow, thank you, @Kaito!

Is the integrity attributive even needed? Or, can I remove it?

I can't understand whether it is important to have that attribute or not. I find that sometimes it is left out. Your thoughts?

Comment: Also, I just copied and pasted those CSS/JS links from the Bootsrap Tour site. I wonder how it turned so wrong ;-(

Comment: Lastly, I have no issues with the 3rd part of the fix, it's a simple copy and paste of your edit. Although, I am having trouble putting together the right links for the 1st and 2nd issue you mention. My problem is, that, I am working on a platform that does not allow me to host my own files, so I am relying on hosted files elsewhere, like on CDN, for the JQuery and Bootsrap links.

Comment: You can look at a different CDN providers such as [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-tour). You can hover over the file you want and click Copy Link with Tag SRI. They have links for jquery, bootstrap and tour. You don't NEED the attribute, it just ensures that the downloaded file downloaded correctly.